# How does GZIP decompression work in chunks?

Tags: java, compression, gzip

I am using GZIP compression to compress the file. Consider the code snippet for decompressing

```
public static void decompress(File compressed, File raw)
    throws IOException
{
    InputStream in =
        new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(compressed));
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(raw);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
    int len;
    while((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Please clarify me the following

1. Will this decompress the file in chunks (ie; decompress the file content which is read in the buffer only)
2. Will this be same as decompressing the entire file (ie; by providing very large buffer size). If so how?
3. How many bytes are read by GZIP algorithm to compress/decompress for a single turn? Will this read by bytes or will GZIP read the entire content in buffer to compress/decompress?
4. Compression rate between file compressed in chunks and entire file?

Comment: This won't *compress* anything.

Comment: Sorry, It's my mistake. Have just attached the sample code for decompression.

Comment: There is no GZIP decompression here, although there should be. Compressing to a file works the same way as compressing to any other stream, and conversely dpso does decompression. The motivation for your question is obscure. Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Comment: My motive of knowing here is will gzip file compression differs i) when we input the entire file and ii) when we read the file in buffer and provide the buffer content to compressed write gzip compression.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it will decompress in chunks.
2. Yes, the result will be the same as decompressing it as one chunk. (Though your code will never do that, no matter how big `buffer` is.)
3. The decompressor itself will use as many bytes as it is given, and will decompress as much as possible from those bytes.
4. Your code does not compress. If it did, the answer is that the compressed result is unaffected by the chunking, unless flush operations are inserted.

Comment: I couldn't get the fourth point where you have said that `unless flush operations are inserted` this won't affect the compression ratio. Can you please explain me how? TIA.

Comment: The compressed data is accumulated in a buffer in the compression state. Exactly the same operations are performed by the compressor whether you feed it one byte at a time or a gigabyte at a time.

Comment: can you explain me a bit more on `how the compressor works like the same whether we feed it one byte at a time or a gigabyte at a time` please..

Comment: The word "buffer" should make it obvious.

Comment: Then please consider the case where i am compressing a file using gzip (via a java program with buffer size X) and another with right clicking on the file -> compress to compress the file. Both gave me the same result. Can you please explain how this happens ? Will the buffer size have impact on resulting compression?
Someone please help me to know more about this.

Comment: I answered that already. No. All else being equal, _the buffer size will not affect the result._ However, using different software, and/or with different options may affect the result. So you should not expect that compressing with a gzip library will give the same result as compressing with a command line gzip utility -- they may be different code.)